# HTML Formatting Bug in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

I am trying to load a html string as
    NSString *htmlData = @"This is a  &lt;b&gt; bold text &lt;/b&gt;  ";

```
    [aWebView loadHTMLString:htmlData baseURL:nil];
```

but i am not getting the out as bold text. Its just displaying the output as  **bold text**

What am i doing wrong ?

I guess this is a bug in WebView , as it is not able to render the htmlentities properly.

Thanks
Biranchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure from your question what you want exactly, some of the markup has been likely eaten by stackoverflow.

Anyway this HTML:

```
This is a  &amp;lt;b&amp;gt; bold text &amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;
```

display as:

```
This is a  &lt;b&gt; bold text &lt;/b&gt;
```

Whereas this HTML:

```
This is a  &lt;b&gt; bold text &lt;/b&gt;
```

displays as:

```
This is a  <b>bold text </b>
```

Finally this:

```
This is a  <b>bold text </b>
```

display actual bold text:

This is a  **bold text**